# How to reorder the inbox list in the Mail app

Tags: ios, email, iphone

I check 3 email accounts on the iPhone.  So under 'All Inboxes' in the email app, there are 3 entries.  How do I reorder the 3 inboxes?  I'd like to put the inbox that's currently 3rd in the list to be 1st in the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the accounts and re-enter them in the order you want them to appear.

Comment: In my experience I had to do the same thing.

Comment: That is not the answer I was hoping for....